# Since C++ doesn't have a standard ABI, how is it possible I can just link to Qt from the package manager?

Tags: c++, abi

Whether I use gcc or clang, I can just link to to the same system wide `libQt5Core.so.5`. Yet C++ doesn't have a standardized ABI, and you are supposed to compile the `.so` files with the same compiler (and compiler version) as your main executable, if the libraries use a C++ API. How is it possible that I don't have to do it in this case?

Comment: But you do it in this case.

Comment: clang deliberately maintains a significant level of ABI compatibility with gcc.    (I'm not sure, offhand, if it is 100% compatibility, but I'm sure you could find out).

Comment: @Peter A "significant" level of ABI compatibility seems pretty vague, how can they ensure that the libs in the packager just work? When I was compiling my own `.so` files and just used a different gcc version than in the main executable (gcc 8 on the libs and 9 on the executable), I immediately got a segfault when running it. Is there some info on what versions of which compilers are compatible? I tried using the abicheck tool, but the output of that looks like nonsense.